# mysql_fetch_array doesn't render the expect values of the SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

In the phpMyAdmin interface I run the following SQL query:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE family = '1' AND type = 'B1'
```

and receive the following results:

'1', '18546269', '51534064' which are correct.

Then I wrote the following code in PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE family = '1' AND type = 'B1'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo '(', implode(',',$array) ,')';
```

But receive the following result:
(1,1) which I didn't expected.

I thought that (1,18546269,51534064) would be displayed.
Then I wrote the following code to verify what should be displayed:

```
print_r ($array);
```

and was very surprised that the values were:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 ).
```

In the end I wrote:

```
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $array['id'],',';
}
```

and as expected received exactly this:

1,18546269,51534064,

which I can't use because I need a string exactly like that: (1,18546269,51534064).
In fact I 'just' need a variable that gives me the same values of the SQL query that I run in phpMyAdmin.
I'm really confused and would be great if one of you guys could help me.
Solutions with mysqli would be appreciated as well. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE family = '1' AND type = 'B1'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$ids = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) $ids .= $row['id'].',';

// Filter the text a bit
$ids = rtrim($string, ',');
$ids = '('.$ids.')';
echo $ids;
```

You basically initiate a variable, put all the ids in it, remove the last comma, append the brackets and that's it.

Comment: That's why I said mysqli solutions would be appreciated. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user3499881 Edited to MySQLi

Comment: It works, but we have to change $ids = rtrim($string, ','); with that:
$ids = rtrim($ids, ',');
Unfortunately I don't have 15 points reputation to vote up! Soon as I reach this, you receive my vote. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array):

> #### Return Values
>
> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or `FALSE` if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on how `result_type` is defined. By using `MYSQL_BOTH` (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> #### Example #2 mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_NUM
>
> ```
> <?php
> mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
>     die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
> mysql_select_db("mydb");
>
> $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");
>
> while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
>     printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
> }
>
> mysql_free_result($result);
> ?>
> ```

That is to say, the function returns only one row, by default as an array consisting of both associative and numeric-indexed columns from the resultset.  You want instead make multiple calls to the function, with a suitable `result_type` parameter (as shown above).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but using
 while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
  printf($array['0'].',');
gives me following result 18546269,51534064,
The first record somehow doesn't appear.
And by the way, how could I use it as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array fetches array of row, not array of column. That means, if you would have ID and name, the fetched array would contain on each row an id and a name.

Quite a simple modification of your code that should fix the problem would be

```
$i=0;
$data=array();
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $data[$i]=$array['id'];
     $i++;
}
echo '(', implode(',',$data) ,')';
```

Comment: You're forgetting to increment $i.. please add that so I can upvote your answer.

Comment: @ChosenWann Thanks, sorry.

Comment: We have to fix the following:
$data[$i]=$array['id']; ($ was missing before i)
but now I receive only the last record of the select.
(51534064)

Comment: @user3499881 Edited. Did you add the next line with $i++ ? I was adding it later (after previous comment), so that may be the problem with only last record showing.

Comment: Now I wrote with $i++ too and it looks better. But it doesn't show the first record. I modified the query (now without type=B1) to receive more values and now we have 12 values, but the first record is still missing.